# Change Entityqueue autocomplete to an entity widget

Tags: entities, nodes

I have an Entityqueue and whenever a user wants to add an item to queue, he/she should write part of title in Autocomplete to add it to queue.

I want to change this autocomplete with a widget that list entities with pagination and when user clicks on an Entity title to add it to queue.

Comment: What about module [References Dialog](https://www.drupal.org/project/references_dialog)? Here is good [video instruction](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z0DITcBIbEw) on youtube

Answer (score 1):

Finally i solved it using Entity API & Entity reference view widget.

Entityqueue is prefect but it suffers from lake of good UX.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried altering the form and change the autocomplete with select list.
If not try that once and render theme table for every 10 titles and also ADD Item (Use Default).
In form submit get entity id and append to $form_state['values']['eq_node'][LANGUAGE_NONE].
Only these changes will help you, rest will be same as default.
If you face any issues please share the errors you got(if any).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to dont use nodequeue, i used that module allot and i surrender for the end users sucks, i recommend you:
[Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) & [Flag Weights](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag_weights) Create a view called My queue and add the contents all what you want and the flag, just try it would be much better for end user and alot personalizable with normal views end.

Comment: Even though I also like the modules you recommended, I wonder if you are not mixing nodequeue with entityqueue. More details from its project page: (a) a rewrite of Nodequeue for Drupal 7 based on entities and (b) provides Views integration, by adding an Entityqueue relationship to your view, and adding a sort for Entityqueue position.